# What language is the Facebook Questions application written in?

Tags: php, facebook

What languages are Facebook Questions coded in? PHP? What else?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook in general uses a compiled version of PHP known as HPHP, or HipHop, which basically converts PHP code into compiled c++ code: http://blogs.oracle.com/opal/2010/02/facebooks_hphp_initial_comment.html